# Stop iCalendar from automatically accepting any incoming meeting

Tags: email, calendar, ical

For the past two days, I've been struggling with this issue.
Every meeting invite I have received on my company email gets automatically accepted on the native Calendar app and it wasn't like that before. I don't remember changing any setting and I'd like to decide which meetings I want to be in.

If it helps, the company email is like a Microsoft Exchange email and I'm on Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261)

Here's a screenshot of the invite in "Replied" tab with accepted pressed instead of in the "New" with the status to be selected.

[image]

Comment: On this forum, a MS representative says the behavior is by design, which seems pretty stupid to me: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-auto-accepting-calendar-invites-on-a/fb8f70f6-6de8-41a6-8e04-b89590caa98a